# CSS transitions in different directions

Tags: css, css-transitions, transition

I am trying to fill a wrapper (600x600px) when hovering over smaller boxes inside it. For a box in the top left corner, it is easily done using regular transition-timing-function, but when trying to enlarge in other directions, I have gotten stuck.

So I have the following:

```
#allbox {
  background: #bbb;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0
}
```

with boxes:

```
div.box1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
}

div.box2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 37.5%;
}
```

For transition I use:

```
#div1 {-webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;}
#div1 {transition-timing-function: linear;}
div.box1:hover {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
}
```

But I am unable to figure a good way to do it for the following box.

Comment: Need your HTML part to understand it properly. Please edit the question and add HTML part too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample using `z-index` keeping the hovered on top.

```css
#allbox {
  background: #bbb;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0
}
#allbox div {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0%;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 50%;
  transition: left 0.5s linear, width 0.5s linear, height 0.5s linear, z-index 1s linear;
}
div.box1 {
  left: 0;
  background: blue;
}
div.box2 {
  left: 33.33%;
  background: red;
}
div.box3 {
  left: 66.66%;
  background: green;
}
#allbox div:hover {
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: left 0.5s linear, width 0.5s linear, height 0.5s linear, z-index 0s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="allbox">
  <div class="box1">  
  </div>
  <div class="box2">  
  </div>
  <div class="box3">  
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we just add "**left: 0;**" to the hover state.

```
div.box2:hover {
  left: 0;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
}
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: No, the box1 works just fine. It is the following box2 which I struggle with. http://imgur.com/i99wKT8 <- something like this

Comment: Sorry my friend, my mistake. I just update it. Hope this work for you.